# Restrict access in apache config to django staff users

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I want to use django's user system to restrict access to locations on my apache server which are not served by django (specifically in my case a location which is a CalDAV endpoint). In particular I'd like to be able to specify that only django staff members can access them, but I can't see how to do that.

My configuration at the moment looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName cal.myhost.net

        WSGIDaemonProcess cal.myhost.net python-path=... user=cal group=cal home=...
        WSGIProcessGroup cal.myhost.net
        WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/python/django-site/calendar_wsgi.py

        <Directory /usr/local/python/django-site>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Calendar access"
                AuthBasicProvider wsgi
                WSGIAuthUserScript /usr/local/python/django-site/access_wsgi.py
                Require valid-user
        </Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

access_wsgi.py is a pretty vanilla access WSGI file and looks like:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.contrib.auth.handlers.modwsgi import check_password
```

I know I could work around this either by adding a django group to the users I want to allow access to and using `WSGIAuthGroupScript`, but I'd like to know if there is a way using the apache config to test for staff-status.

Comment: You are only doing an authentication check, not an authorisation check. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/#authorization-with-mod-wsgi-and-django-groups Note that ``Require group secret-agents`` may need to ``Require wsgi-group secret-agents`` depending on Apache version used. Also obviously change the group you are checking.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton surely the `Require valid-user` is the authorization check..? Just not a very restrictive one :-)

Comment: Nope. In Apache that is merely the trigger which requires a user be authenticated. Take that out and authentication will not even be done. Authorisation is triggered by ``Require group``, ``Require ldap-group``, ``Require wsgi-group`` and similar. So, user first has to be authenticated, then authorisation checks based on group membership of that user can be done. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

Comment: Huh, well that's confusing since that very page says at the bottom of the [Getting it Working](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking) section that "the Require directive provides the authorization part of the process", and, after all, Require is provided by mod_authz_core, the authorization module...

Comment: I'll have to check, but in practice, if you don't have ``Require valid-user``, then it would allow through anyone, whether authentication succeeded or not. So it acts as the gateway for whether authentication was successful as I understand it. So to me it forms a part of the authentication.